# Python editor with autocompletion function in imported module

Tags: python, function, object, module, editor

is there a python editor has autocompletion function in imported module ? 
i think like Jcreator for java function completion and argument hints.

thanks,
Guns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org/) for Eclipse supports autocompletion.

Answer (score 3):

As a geek I'd recommend Emacs + Rope, but more common options are:

- PyDev for Eclipse (free)
- PyCharm (very good for its price)

You can find a big list of available Python editors [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors).

Comment: Trivial edits are frowned upon here, so i'll comment that it's "his/hers/its".